# Why cout is producing no output on Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, iostream, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Whatever";

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Cout does not work, nor printf, nor puts, nor anything. Also, I've checked the project properties and both the debug and release are set to "Console Application" and to "Pause in the end". It makes no sense.

Edit: Also, I've tried to flush with endl before (No results).

Comment: Change `cout << "Whatever";` to `cout << "Whatever" << endl;`

Comment: Try printing an endline. I think I had this issue once.

Comment: Still does not work (I've tried to flush before).

Comment: Try more variations. Try an endl before you print, after, write a loop that prints 100 times...

Comment: works fine on my version... 13.12, restart the pc or reinstall code blocks

Comment: @RederickDeathwill - In case you run the program from inside the debugger, try to run it directly in a console. Maybe your debugger redirects stdout to something strange.

Comment: remove -mwindows from the compiler options; this is for GUI applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am writing my comment as a response: 
Your image shows option "-mwindows", that removes the console, as said at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ (MinGW FAQs)

```
How do I remove DOS command windows?
    In the link step add a "-mwindows" switch to the command line.
```

Comment: It did not work, but I've solved it. I had to create another project on Code Blocks (For some reason, that project was cranky. Nonetheless, I'm giving you the right answer, since I did not know that this actually removes DOS command.