# Code::Blocks does not show any output

Tags: c, console, printf, output, codeblocks

I  installed Code::Blocks 16.01 along with the MinGW compiler.I created a project just to test it out,  built and run the default code in the default main.c that's included when I made the project.

But when the console shows up I don't see anything in the output, besides "Process ended" data.

`Hello World!` doesn't show up.

[Workspace + "output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkbGB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the `main.c` file and not something else?
If so then try this:

```
void main(){
     printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your workspace builds, if it uses option -mwindows just remove its, details:
[Why cout is producing no output on Code Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862154/why-cout-is-producing-no-output-on-code-blocks)